# returning PHP values back from an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to return php values (using json ) back from an Ajax call but rather than just returning the json data its returning the entire page.

further the json data type does not work ;ry script.

i.e if i place this:

```
dataType : 'json',
```

within my ajax call  the Ajax will simply not work.

**Jquery Script**

below is my ajax call

**SENDING PAGE  (please note ; it only works if i take out the datatype **

```
$('.option1').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  

        var ipAddress = '<?php echo getIP(); ?>';
        var Results = $(this).data("value");

        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/testSite/cms/index.php?view=responcePage',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {
            'ip_address'  : ipAddress, 
            'results': Results,

        },
        success: function(data){

     //    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          alert(data);
        }
        });
```

**RETURNING PAGE:**

```
$data = array("percentage"   => "$percent" );

echo json_encode($data);
```

**returned data**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<body>

 {"percentage":"83""}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be sending any HTML with your response.

Comment: That's his point. He's sending back an encoded array, and strangely, some HTML is added. He's asking why and how to avoid that.

Comment: Use php `die();` for preventing the full page load after the `json_encode()`

Comment: `dataType: json` will accept data back in JSON format and it will be directly available. If you do not include that, you will need to use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Nice one. Maybe there's something after your echo json_encode($data), that returns some additional HTML? Use die() to be sure and stop the PHP there. Shah Rukh is right.

Comment: are you using a framework for your back end? maybe a cms/framework/template is adding a generic header/footer

Comment: Also, try $.getJSON instead of $.ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

You can start by adding a specific header to your php script 
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

By the way it seems strange to have this html auto generated. What's your source code (ctrl+U) when you open the target file in your browser ?
http://localhost/testSite/cms/index.php?view=responcePage?ip_address=&results=

Comment: hi Jona303. sorry. i am not clear. how do you mean, add a php script header. where do i add that?

Comment: You can fild a complete documentation here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php .
But I dont' think it will solve your problem. It's a kind of "best-pratices".
What about the comment of atmd ? (are you using a framework ? )